# Why is my express 4 middleware not being called?

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following Express 4 code:

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var log = require('npmlog');
var httpStatus = require('http-status-codes');

var config = require('./config');

var routes = require('./routes');

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    log.verbose('Express', '%s %s', req.method, req.url); //Never called
    next();
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    if(err) {
        res.status(httpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send(err.message); //Never called
    }
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', routes);

mongoose.connect(config.mongoAddress,
    {keepAlive: 1, server: {auto_reconnect: true}},
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            log.error('Mongo', 'Could not connect to mongo database');
            throw err;
        } else {
            log.info('Mongo', 'Successfully established connection to ' + config.mongoAddress);
        }
    }
);

var server = app.listen(config.port, function () {
    log.info('Server', 'Server listening at %s', server.address().port);
});
```

My route is working fine, however both functions I have before `app.use(bodyParser.json());` are never being called (I also tried adding breakpoints, to no avail). I also tried putting those functions AFTER the route is added, which didn't help (but that was expected).

What am I forgetting?

Comment: just read [this](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use) once, and you will easily be able to solve it. Look into the syntax and desc of middleware usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is this:

You're including your routes BEFORE you define your middleware. What you should be doing is something like this:

```
var app = express();

// setup all middlewares here
app.use(...);
app.use(...);

// include all routes here
app.use(routera);
app.use(routerb);
```

Comment: That seems to be right. I thought the route was defined when I did `app.use('/api', routes);`, however they are defined when I do `var routes = require('routes');` because in routes.js I have `route.post(...);` and `module.exports = router;`